# How to get both input?

Tags: python

There is an HTML element

```
<form action="/login" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="16d372e503adcfdb6ed1929d1318f4fb.1585319930.52116411" /><input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="4a1c844bdf1bc00c0c02742d0aecb226.1585319930.52239339" />
```

How to get both values?
I managed to get only the first

```
value = soup.find_all('input', {'name': 'PHPSESSID'}).get('value')
```

i need to get

```
print(value)
print(value1)
```

Comment: How are you using python with HTML?

Comment: receive PHPSESSID from both fields input

Comment: `soup.find_all` returns an iterator; you'll need something like `values = [e.get('value') for e in soup.find_all('input', {'name': 'PHPSESSID'})]`

Comment: Please would you give full details of what you are doing here? Seems like you are using Beautiful Soup. Could you give full details of how you set this up and all the code that you have tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly then try this:

```
inputs = soup.find_all('input', {'name': 'PHPSESSID'})
print(inputs[0].get("value"))
print(inputs[1].get("value"))
```

Output:

```
16d372e503adcfdb6ed1929d1318f4fb.1585319930.52116411
4a1c844bdf1bc00c0c02742d0aecb226.1585319930.52239339
```